# Python on Cygwin - Can't use up-down arrows after modifying PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, cygwin, pythonpath

I'm running python 2.7.12 on the most recent Cygwin x64 install. I started out my python ventures with Enthought's Canopy IDE, right now my PYTHONPATH looks like this

> $ echo $PYTHONPATH
>
> C:\Users\ME\AppData\local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages

Cygwin doesn't like this path, so I tried

> $ export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/cygdrive/c/Users/ME/AppData/local/Enthought/Canopy/User/lib/site-packages/"

This allows me to load modules that have been installed here correctly, but after doing this, in my python interactive shell, pressing the arrow keys no longer works like they used to. Before, I could press the up/down arrow keys to cycle through my python history, and the left and right arrow keys to go back and forth on the current line to modify things, like a normal bash prompt. Now, pressing arrow keys moves the cursor on the screen (so if I press up, my cursor goes literally upward onto already-evaluated lines) and (to my understanding) it adds in invisible uninterpretable characters that make the command fail, so I have to retype it from scratch.

If I set PYTHONPATH back to what it was originally, this problem goes away, but I can't load my modules using the command line python...I strongly believe setting my PYTHONPATH variable to where my packages are is what's causing this problem.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know why it is happening. However, I suggest that you try creating a symbolic link to the Windows location of your modules in your Cygwin directory, and then include that in your PYTHONPATH variable.

Comment: can you echo `PYTHONPATH` before modifying it and post it here?

Comment: I tried the symlink, plopped it in my home directory and added it to my PYTHONPATH, but unfortunately the behavior persists...Also the first command I printed is the normal output of echoing PYTHONPATH, but I reran and posted the entire command as well

Comment: can you try `export PYTHONPATH=C:\\Users\\ME\\AppData\\local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages` or `export PYTHONPATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/ME/AppData/local/Enthought/Canopy/User/lib/site-packages`

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I tried them both out. The first didn't seem to be recognized as a path by cygwin, the second did (after capitalizing local and lib, and replacing your "o" in "Canopy", it was encoded weirdly when I pasted it) but gave the cursor error

Comment: I know that you're using Cygwin, not Linux, but I know that Linux relies heavily on Python 2. What I am wondering is whether the modules that you have in your Canopy directory are somehow interfering with the Cygwin environment. I also use Cygwin64, and I know that it offers Python3 in addition to Python 2. I suggest trying everything in Python 3, and seeing what happens.

Comment: You bring up a really interesting point there. I've found that directly adding folders from the Canopy site-packages to my /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages allows me to use them. I guess two hacky fixes would be either making a new "pip" command that runs pip and then symlinks the folder to python2.7's site-packages, or making a small bash script that runs python $1 -c "import sys; sys.path.append('/cygdrive/c/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Enthought/Canopy/User/Lib/site-packages')". I've found both to work, and while they're not ideal fixes, they meet my requirements. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Which python are you using. At the cygwin sell prompt, execute `which -a python`  and then `python -V`. The answers will tell us if you are running a windows or cygwin python. Try leaving the PYTHONPATH alone. Install extras using `python -m pip install -U xxxxxx`. Note that wndows python does not work well from bash prompt in mintty wndow, and cygwin python does not work well in cmd shell in command window. You may need to install cygwin python and install extras using cygwin python's pip to get readline editing to work properly.